# LiveData Observer isn't triggered for the second time

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, android-livedata, clean-architecture

I'm expecting that the observer will be triggered when I'm hitting API by clicking one of the side menu. When I clicked one of the menu, `Retrofit` actually gave me the response with the correct value. The problem is, the `Observer` isn't getting triggered for the second time. I've trace the problem and find out that my `Repository` isn't returning a value even though my Retrofit already update the `MutableLiveData`.

`RemoteDataSource.kt`

```kotlin
    override fun getDisastersByFilter(filter: String?): LiveData<ApiResponse<DisastersDTO?>> {
        val result = MutableLiveData<ApiResponse<DisastersDTO?>>()

        apiService.getDisastersByFilter(filter).enqueue(object : Callback<DisastersResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<DisastersResponse>,
                response: Response<DisastersResponse>
            ) {
                if(response.isSuccessful) {
                    val data = response.body()
                    data?.disastersDTO?.let {
                        result.postValue(ApiResponse.Success(it))
                        Log.d("RemoteDataSource", "$it")
                    } ?: run {
                        result.postValue(ApiResponse.Error("Bencana alam tidak ditemukan"))
                    }
                } else {
                    result.postValue(ApiResponse.Error("Terjadi kesalahan!"))
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DisastersResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                result.postValue(ApiResponse.Error(t.localizedMessage!!))
                Log.d("RemoteDataSource", t.localizedMessage!!)
            }

        })

        return result
    }
```

`Repository.kt`

```kotlin
    override fun getDisastersByFilter(filter: String?): LiveData<Resource<List<Disaster>>> =
        remoteDataSource.getDisastersByFilter(filter).map {
            when (it) {
                is ApiResponse.Empty -> Resource.Error("Terjadi error")
                is ApiResponse.Error -> Resource.Error(it.errorMessage)
                is ApiResponse.Loading -> Resource.Loading()
                is ApiResponse.Success -> Resource.Success(
                    DataMapper.disastersResponseToDisasterDomain(
                        it.data
                    )
                )
            }
        }
```

`SharedViewModel.kt`

```kotlin
    fun getDisastersByFilter(filter: String? = "gempa"): LiveData<Resource<List<Disaster>>> =
        useCase.getDisastersByFilter(filter)
Here's the **MapsFragment**

    private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
    viewModel.getDisastersByFilter("gempa").observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            when (it) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    Log.d("MapsFragmentFilter", "${it.data}")
                    it.data?.let { listDisaster ->
                        if(listDisaster.isNotEmpty()) {
                            map.clear()
                            addGeofence(listDisaster)
                            listDisaster.map { disaster ->
                                placeMarker(disaster)
                                addCircle(disaster)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                is Resource.Error -> Toast.makeText(context, "Filter Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                is Resource.Loading -> {}
            }
        }
```

Here's the `MainActivity` that triggers the function to hit API

```kotlin
    private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
    binding.navViewMaps.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menu ->
            when (menu.itemId) {
                R.id.filter_gempa -> viewModel.getDisastersByFilter("gempa")
                R.id.filter_banjir -> viewModel.getDisastersByFilter("banjir")
                R.id.about_us -> viewModel.getDisasters()
            }

            binding.drawerLayoutMain.closeDrawers()

            true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure from what you've posted, but your menu options call `getDisastersByFilter` on your `SharedViewModel`, and it looks like that eventually calls through to `getDisastersByFilter` in `RemoteDataSource`.

That function **creates a new `LiveData` and returns it**, and all your other functions (including the one in `viewModel`) just return that new `LiveData`. So if you want to see the result that's eventually posted to it, you need to `observe` that new one.

I don't know where the fragment code you posted is from, but it looks like you're just calling and observing `viewModel.getDisastersByFilter` *once*. So when that first happens, it does the data fetch and you get a result on the `LiveData` it returned. That `LiveData` won't receive any more results, from the looks of your code - it's a one-time, disposable thing that receives a result later, and then it's useless.

---

If I've got that right, you need to rework how you're handling your `LiveData`s. The fragment needs to get the result of every `viewModel.getDisastersByFilter` call, so it can observe the result - it might be better if your activity passes an event to the fragment ("this item was clicked") and the fragment handles calling the VM, and it can observe the result while it's at it (pass it to a function that wires that up so you don't have to keep repeating your observer code)

The other approach would be to have the Fragment observe a `currentData` livedata, that's wired up to show the value of a *different* source livedata. Then when you call `getDisastersByFilter`, that source livedata is swapped for the new one. The `currentData` one gets any new values posted to this new source, and the fragment only has to observe that single `LiveData` once. All the data gets piped into it by the VM.

I don't have time to do an example, but have a look at this Transformations stuff (this is one of the developers' blogs): https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-beyond-the-viewmodel-reactive-patterns-using-transformations-and-mediatorlivedata-fda520ba00b7

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you are doing wrong is using LiveData in the first place while using a retrofit.

You are getting a response asynchronously while your code is running synchronously. So, you need to make use of suspending functions by using `suspend`.

And while calling this function from ViewModel, wrap it with `viewModelScope.launch{}`

```
fun getDisastersByFilter(filter: String? = "gempa") = viewModelScope.launch {
    useCase.getDisastersByFilter(filter).collect{
  // do something....
  // assign the values to MutableLiveData or MutableStateFlows
  }
}
```

You should either be using RxJava or CallbackFlow.

I prefer Flows, given below is an example of how your code might look if you use callback flow.

```
    suspend fun getDisastersByFilter(filter: String?): Flow<ApiResponse<DisastersDTO?>> =
        callbackFlow {

            apiService.getDisastersByFilter(filter)
                .enqueue(object : Callback<DisastersResponse> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<DisastersResponse>,
                        response: Response<DisastersResponse>
                    ) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            val data = response.body()
                            data?.disastersDTO?.let {
                                trySend(ApiResponse.Success(it))
//                                result.postValue(ApiResponse.Success(it))
                                Log.d("RemoteDataSource", "$it")
                            } ?: run {
                                trySend(ApiResponse.Error("Bencana alam tidak ditemukan"))
//                                result.postValue(ApiResponse.Error("Bencana alam tidak ditemukan"))
                            }
                        } else {
                            trySend(ApiResponse.Error("Terjadi kesalahan!"))
//                            result.postValue(ApiResponse.Error("Terjadi kesalahan!"))
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<DisastersResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                        trySend(ApiResponse.Error(t.localizedMessage!!))
//                        result.postValue(ApiResponse.Error(t.localizedMessage!!))
                        Log.d("RemoteDataSource", t.localizedMessage!!)
                    }

                })
            awaitClose()
        }
```